# Using Solr as a datastore

Tags: java, solr, lucene, database, nosql

We are evaluating Solr to replace our existed Lucene based data service.

In our existed implementation, Lucene is used for indexing domain objects, and those domain objects are serialised and stored in Berkeley DB.

We now thousands of millions of domain objects, which in total account for about 100G data to be indexed and it will double every year, so scalability is the foremost requirement on anything we want to use.

Solr seems quite capable in the Indexing/Searching part of the job with all the slice/shard function it support.

Now we need to decide if we want to keep the Berkley DB as the object store, or, simple put the serialised object into Solr as a store but not indexed field. Although the architecture will be much simpler, given the size of the data we are not quite sure if it is a good idea, and indeed there are many blog post we read suggest against it.

Has any one had similar problem? How much performance hit are we expecting from doing this, if we indeed put everything in Solr. Any experience or reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need to do with the data: how frequently you add compared to how frequently you query and update, what kind of queries you need to make, how big documents you have, etc.

For example if you have nested objects and need to query them using Solr's blockjoin then your index will get bigger faster.

Solr/Lucene was not designed to be a primary storage so you may miss some of the features that you use in Berkeley DB - you need to have a look what those are, if any.

Your scalability needs should be taken care of by Solr cloud.

It's also a matter of trade-off: a simple system with a single storage means less inconsistencies, less complexity, potentially faster updates. On the other hand, you might lose some functionality and you could hit unexpected bottlenecks based on your data and queries.

100GB of data is not *that* much. You could easily do an experiment and index 10GB, 20GB, ... 100GB of *your data*, measure the size of the index, and measure query response times and throughput (on *your queries*, including those for which you might have used Berkeley DB before). That should give you a good idea about the technology and its suitability in your case.

Any particular reason why you're preferring Solr over ElasticSearch?